# How to create "workers" using bash?

Tags: bash, worker

I'd like to run some different scripts simultanously using bash.
All of them say something to an screen-session.

**What we have:**

```
worker=1

while [[ ! -f "worker$worker.sh" ]]; do
if [[ ! -f "worker$worker.sh" ]]; then

cat >worker$worker.sh <<EOL

#some code with variables which change and say something to an screen session#

EOL

chmod a+x worker$worker.sh 
./worker$worker.sh
break
else
(( worker ++ ))
continue
fi
done
```

The current code does not work :/ What's wrong?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [GNU parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-parallel/info).

Comment: @Cyrus I'll check this out, thx.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Consider including a description of what you expected to happen and then a description of what actually happens (including any commands you run and what they output). It's especially helpful if people can see the same behavior by running your posted script themselves (instead of you running a different/full version and then reporting on what *that* does without letting anyone see the code)

Comment: Please add a simple example of *"saying something to a screen session"*.

Answer (score 3):

`tmux` is an alternative to `screen`.

GNU Parallel has an interface to `tmux`, so try this:

```
parallel --fg --delay 0.1 --tmuxpane ::: worker*.sh
parallel --fg --delay 0.1 --tmux ::: worker*.sh
```

If you do not need the `tmux` interface:

```
parallel ::: worker*.sh
```

Start by watching the intro videos for a quick introduction:
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Then look at the EXAMPLEs after the list of OPTIONS (Use LESS=+/EXAMPLE: man parallel). That will give you an idea of what GNU parallel is capable of.

Then spend an hour walking through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: I have never seen **GNU Parallel** used with `tmux`! I tried a simple example and it says `Can't join a pane to its own window`? I just did `parallel --fg --tmuxpane 'echo {}; sleep 3' ::: 4 5 6 7`

Comment: Yeah. You experience a race condition. Add `--delay 0.1`.